# How can I get Textile to create links out of plain URL's?

Tags: ruby, textile, redcloth

Many of my users are typing in plain URL's and not using the Textile format for creating links. I would like Textile to just make the URL's linkable to the URL's. I don't really need to worry about XSS or anything malicious because it is an internal network with a very small group of users. What would be the best way to go about achieving this functionality?

I am using the Ruby version of RedCloth.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
def urls2links( s )
  s.gsub(
    /([^:])((https?|ftp)\:\/\/[^\s)'"]+[^.,)\s])(. |, |[\s]|\) | )/, 
    '\1<a href="\2" target="_blank">\2</a>\4')
end

def textile2html( s )
  textilize(urls2links(s)).html_safe
end
```

Use this text to test it:

```
Plain urls converted to external links by my textile2html helper:
* http://www.google.com 
* http://www.google.com, 
* http://www.google.com.
```

Comment: Edit your answer for others to see the full answer at once and there is no need to read all comments

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if RedCloth can turn URLs into clickable links, but there's a Rails text helper called [auto_link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link) that can.

Comment: Interesting. I am already sending the data through Textile so sending it through another parser isn't exactly what I want to do.